# How to create an arithmetic expression with lenght of items in each row of a column using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
data = {'id': ['id_01, id_02', 
               'id_03', 
               'id_04', 
               'id_05', 
               'id_06, id_07, id_08'], 
        'price': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

output:

[image]

I did this to split each id and analyse each as single row:

```
new_df = df.assign(new_id=df.id.str.split(",")).explode('new_id')
new_df
```

output:

[image]

So far, so good =)
Now I'd like to reach this result below, where I calculate each price divided by the lenght of id items in each row, like this:

[image]

How can I reach this result using the most simple way for a beginner student?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate this before you explode when you can access the length of  `id` items via `.str.len()`:

```
(df.assign(new_id=df.id.str.split(","))
   .assign(new_price=lambda df: df.price / df.new_id.str.len())
   .explode('new_id'))

                    id  price  new_id   new_price
0         id_01, id_02    100   id_01   50.000000
0         id_01, id_02    100   id_02   50.000000
1                id_03    200   id_03  200.000000
2                id_04    300   id_04  300.000000
3                id_05    400   id_05  400.000000
4  id_06, id_07, id_08    500   id_06  166.666667
4  id_06, id_07, id_08    500   id_07  166.666667
4  id_06, id_07, id_08    500   id_08  166.666667
```

Comment: Great solution, @Psidom!! Thanks a lot you all. I'll now try to figure out a way to reproduce this for multiple columns of price_2, price_3, price_4. I intend to run the calculations for the four columns of prices at once, and after that, I'll explode the ids. Will it work with this logic?

Comment: It should still work with this approach, you might not be able to do it in a one liner though.

Comment: I'm trying to do it in different DFs, and then I'll try to concatenate them into one with inner join. Thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Another way and in one line, str. split into a column, find the len of new list and use it to find average on dynamically. Faster than a lambda.

```
   new_df = (df.assign(new_id=df.id.str.split(","),#new colume
    price=df['price'].div(df.id.str.split(",").str.len())#Find average
                .astype(int)).explode('new_id')#Explode to expnd the df
     )
```

output

```
            id           price  new_id
0         id_01, id_02     50   id_01
0         id_01, id_02     50   id_02
1                id_03    200   id_03
2                id_04    300   id_04
3                id_05    400   id_05
4  id_06, id_07, id_08    166   id_06
4  id_06, id_07, id_08    166   id_07
4  id_06, id_07, id_08    166   id_08
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but you can use the fact that exploded rows have the same index:

```
new_df['new_price'] = new_df['price']/new_df.groupby(new_df.index).transform('count')['id']
```